# Sizeof Structure in C

Tags: c

To find the size of a structure in C

```
struct student
    {
     char name;
     int age;
     float weight;
    };
```

main ()
{
    int i,j,k,l;
    struct student s1;
    i=sizeof(s1.name);
    j=sizeof(s1.age);
    k=sizeof(s1.weight);
    l=sizeof(s1);
    printf ("\n size of name    %d",i);
    printf ("\n size of age     %d",j);
    printf ("\n size of weight  %d",k);
    printf ("\n size of s1      %d",l);

`printf("\n");
}`

My output is:

`size of name    1
 size of age     4
 size of weight  4
 size of s1      12`

But structure size should be the sum of sizes of its members. Why am i getting 12 instead of 9 as size of structure variable s1. Can someone explain what is wrong.

Comment: To find the size of a structure, simply use `sizeof (struct student)`. Incidentally: you need `#include <stdio.h>`, `main ()` should be `int main(void)`, and your `\n`s should be at the *end* of each line of output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For performance or hardware reasons, fields in structures should be suitably aligned. Read about [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) (details depend upon the target processor and the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)).

In your example on x86-64/Linux:

```
struct student {
 char name;
 int age;
 float weight;
};
```

the field `name` has no alignment requirement.
the field `age` needs 4 bytes aligned to a multiple of 4
the field  `weight` needs 4 bytes aligned to a multiple of 4

so the overall `struct student` needs 12 bytes aligned to a multiple of 4

If `weight` was declared `double` it would need 8 bytes aligned to a multiple of 8, and the entire structure would need 16 bytes aligned to 8.

BTW, the type of your `name` field is wrong. Usually names are more than one single char. (My family name needs 13 letters + the terminating null byte, i.e. 14 bytes). Probably you should declare it a pointer `char *name;` (8 bytes aligned to 8) or an array e.g. `char name[16];` (16 bytes aligned to 1 byte).

The [GCC compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/) provides a nice extension: [`__alignof__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alignment.html) and relevant [type attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

If performance or size is important to you, you should put fields in `struct` in order of decreasing alignment requirements (so usually start with the `double` fields, then `long` and pointers, etc...)

Comment: That solved my confusion.